# Generated .d.ts file is not getting the imports correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-typings

My `default.ts` file

```
import { Type, Units } from './Duration.types';
const defaultDuration = {
  type: Type.Dynamic,
  range: {
    count: 12,
    unit: Units.Hours
  }
};
export { defaultDuration }
```

`Type` and `Units` are `enum` and are exported as `export { Type, Units }`

This is my component where I am using it.
`Component.tsx`

```
import { defaultDuration } from './defaults';    
static defaultProps = {
  allowToggle: true,
  duration: defaultDuration
};
```

I did `npm run build` and got a generated `Component.d.ts` file which is showing errors.

```
static defaultProps: {
        allowToggle: boolean;
        duration: {
            type: Type;
            range: {
                count: number;
                unit: Units;
            };
        };
    };
```

The error says that it cannot find `Type` or `Units` inside the `.d.ts` file

When I try to import this `.d.ts` file in some other place, it is throwing the above error.